# Getting colored plane surface instead of texture in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to apply texture on my object. But I am getting no texture applied but just colored plane surface on object means if there is wood texture image that I am applying then it just takes color of texture like brown not actual texture.

**Basic code is like below:**

```
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
var newMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: colorValue, specular: 0xffffff, shininess: 100  } );

loader.load( './models/stl/binary/'+top, function ( newGeometry ) {

newMesh = new THREE.Mesh( newGeometry, newMaterial );

newMesh.position.set(  0,0.6, 0  );
newMesh.rotation.set(0,0.8,0);
newMesh.scale.set( 0.04, 0.04, 0.04 );

scene.add( newMesh );
```

**I tried following for applying texture:**

```
var newMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, specular: 0xffffff, shininess: 100, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/table/lighttexture.jpg" ),
    side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
    newMaterial.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
```

Result of above code is same, just color of texture getting applied.

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "textures/water.jpg" );
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.set( 4, 4 );
                var newMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, specular: 0xffffff, shininess: 100, map: texture } );
```

Getting ERROR on above code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'wrapS' of undefined
```

Can anyone please tell me, how should I get the original texture on my object?

**EDIT**

Texture is working correctly for sphere geometry as in below code.

```
            var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 10, 10);
            var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
            mat.map = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
            "textures/table/lighttexture.jpg");
            mat.transparent = true;
            mat.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
            mat.depthWrite = false;
            mat.color = new THREE.Color(0xff0000);
            var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, mat);
            scene.add(sphere);
```

Comment: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "textures/water.jpg" ); does not return a texture object. You get it by adding a second argument to the load function that will be callback with the texture as the argument.

Comment: @ mrVoid I am new to this. Can you please tell how should I do that?

Comment: I direct you to a question in SO already answered and the documentation. [Loading Textures in threeJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012361/how-can-i-preload-textures-with-three-js) [Documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/TextureLoader)

Answer (score 0):

i suspect your geometry does not have correct uvs
first try to texture a geometry generated by three

```
geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100,100);
```

if the texture shows correctly it means the geometry you load from stl does not have uvs set or it has incorrect values(like all zeros)

to get to the uvs use

```
geometry.faceVertexUvs
```

for Geometry

and

```
geometry.getAttribute("uv")
```

in case you have a BufferGeometry

Comment: I had tried texture for sphere gemetry. It shows the texture correctly. How do I check for my STL object with UVs set? I am unknown with this UVs thing, how should I use that and all. Can you please tell me, how should I set UVs in my STL object?

Comment: please check my EDIT.

Comment: you hav to calculate uv - uvs are coordinates of texture usually going from 0 to 1, [0,0] is the top left corner of the texture, [1,1] is the bottom right, there is no easy way to automatically calculate the uv with threejs especially for a custom loaded object see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774648/three-js-generate-uv-coordinate